# welcoming distinguished guests on to the stage

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I am translating a master of ceremonies script for a gala into English. When inviting distinguished guests onto the stage during the gala (without an extended introduction), what is the most polite way to summon/invite them onto the stage?

I have to include the title of the guest and his name in the invitation which is perplexing somehow. For example is "May I invite the CEO of XXXX, Mr. Smith, to the stage.", appropriate?

What I mean by no extended introduction, is that "there is no need for an introduction for this next guest. This guest has graced the world with his philanthropic activities" etc. which means it's an immediate and short introduction to the guest.

In this context, I believe that the guest is not being invited to give a speech, just to present a prize to someone. I hope this makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: How you phrase it can depend on the cultural norms of the audience. Your “May I invite <position> <formal title> <name> to the stage” sounds fine, though.

Comment: @Lawrence It would also be fine the other way round: "I'd now like to invite Mr Smith, the CEO of XXX, to the stage." There is a slight difference of emphasis with the two forms. If Mr Smith has been invited primarily because of his position (perhaps XXX have sponsored the prize) then the position should come first, if he has been invited because he is a local dignitary the name should come first.